# Microsoft Excel: Using "OR" Function to Compare Non-Numeric Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'll get right to it.  I've included a screenshot to help out with this question.

[image]

Look at cell J24.  I need to write a formula that does the following:

If I24 is equal to "NA", then J24 needs to say "NA".  If I24 is equal to "ND", then it needs to do a calculation,  I I24 is a number, then it needs to do a different calculation.  I was thinking something like this:

IF(I24="NA", "NA", IF(I24="ND", $E$22-H24, IF(ISNUMBER(I24), ($E$22-H24+(0.84*I24), "ERROR")))

I don't think this works though because of the last step in my argument.  Earlier in the equation I basically have this check to see if a cell is equal to "NA" or "ND", which are both non-numeric.  Later in the equation, I have something that's checking whether or not the cell is non-numeric.  So basically, it's going to get to the last part of the equation and say "Oh, I see it says "NA" or "ND" instead of a number, so I'm going to return "FALSE".  Do I just need to rearrange the equation?  Use the AND or OR function with this IF statement?  And if that's the case, how in the world do I combine all these?

I've been trying to figure out how to use the IF function with the OR function by saying something like "IF(OR(I24<>"NA", "ND"), I24, "FAIL).  Is that how you would say "If I24 is not equal to "NA" or "ND""?  Or do I have the syntax wrong?

Comment: Your narrative seems to be mixing up `I24` and `J24`. If the formula is to be put into `J24` then the formula cannot refer to `J24`; that would be a circular reference.

Comment: Okay I went ahead and fixed it.

Comment: `... IF(ISNUMBER(J24), ` needs to be `... IF(ISNUMBER(I24), ...`.

Comment: Ugh, I'm sorry man.  I'm having a *very* bad morning.  Fixed again.

Comment: I've got a formula that should work for all of column J. It is producing the correct numbers (matching yours) in J18:J21 but starts to drift off your sample numbers after J22. In J18 as `=IF(I18="NA", "NA", IF(I18="ND", INDEX(E:E, MATCH(1E+99, E$1:E18))-H18, IF(ISNUMBER(I18), INDEX(E:E, MATCH(1E+99, E$1:E18))-H18+(0.84*I18), "ERROR")))`, fill down.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I actually figured out the answer with a little bit playing around.  This is how it should go:

```
IF(ISNUMBER(I24), ($E$22-H24+(0.84*I24)), IF(I24="NA", "NA", IF(I24="ND", $E22-H24)))
```

I guess what I was trying to figure out at the same time is, why can't you have a function that says:

```
IF(OR(I24<>"NA", "ND"), I24, "ERROR")
```

Isn't that how you say "If I24 is not equal to "NA" or "ND"???  It gives me an error when I try that and says " #VALUE ".

I know it's not quite related, but it is something could be useful in the future if I'm filling out these spreadsheets and I don't have "NA" or "ND".

Comment: `=IF(OR(I24<>{"NA", "ND"}), I24, "ERROR")` That would ALWAYS be `I24` because I24 cannot be both NA and NM at the same time.

Comment: Substitute the `$E$22` for `INDEX(E:E, MATCH(1E+99, E$1:E24))` in both places (on row 24) and you do not have to keep changing `$E$22` when you hit a new grouped range in column E.

Comment: But I'm trying to say the for a cell I currently have highlighted (A1 for simplicity), "If I24 doesn't equal "NA" or "ND", then I want A1 to say what it I24 **DOES** say.  You know?

Comment: If I24 does not equal NA AND I24 does not equal ND then say what I24 is equal to. `=IF(AND(I24<>{"NA","ND"}), I24, "Error")`

Comment: Wow haha, I'm an idiot.  Thank you very much for helping me get that straight...this is definitely not my day.

Comment: You know, it's been almost a year to the day since I ran into you on this board figuring out molecular weights.